# Gene environment interraction analysis

Tags: regression, linear-regression, environment, cox-regression, genetics

I am trying to undestand what would be the best way to analyse whether air pollution(continuous and categorical variable of PM2.5 exposure) in the presence of a specific genetic variant(binary variable) has an impact on a)disease progression b) worse seurvival

I am looking for some help writing the code and what would be the best analysis methodologically